# shiny: Enable sliderInput() based on selection in radioButton()

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, slider, shinyapps

I am having trouble getting this `observeEvent` to work properly.

The `sliderInput()` should only be enabled and accessible if **Yes** is selected in `radioButton()`

What am I missing?

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(


  radioButtons("EXBR", "External Beam Radiation", choiceValues=list("No","Yes"),
               choiceNames=list("No","Yes"), selected ="No", inline=T),
  sliderInput("EXBRGy", "Cumulative Gy dosage", 
              min = 2, max = 60, value = 40)


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$EXBR, {
    if((input$EXBR == "Yes")){
      disable("EXBRGy")
    }else{
      enable("EXBRGy")
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: add `shinyjs::useShinyjs(),` to your `fluidPage` in `ui` (also should add `library(shinyjs)` to your post as well)

Comment: Hi @Ben. Thank you as always. That solved it. Consider posting as answer. I wish you a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using most `shinyjs` functions, you need to call `useShinyjs()` in the app’s `ui`. It’s best to include it near the top as a convention. Also added `library(shinyjs)` and removed extra parentheses in the `if` statement.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  radioButtons("EXBR", "External Beam Radiation", choiceValues=list("No","Yes"),
               choiceNames=list("No","Yes"), selected ="No", inline=T),
  sliderInput("EXBRGy", "Cumulative Gy dosage", 
              min = 2, max = 60, value = 40)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$EXBR, {
    if(input$EXBR == "Yes"){
      disable("EXBRGy")
    }else{
      enable("EXBRGy")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```